# Output HTML as plain text for code example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb, prism.js

I have an application Im building that needs to output some HTML inside a `<pre>` and `<code>` tag. I am using [prism](https://github.com/PrismJS/prism) for the syntax highlighting and it works fine for other languages. The problem is that when I use HTML inside the `code` tag it either renders the html, or won't highlight with prism because it is output as a string.

The markup is:

```
<pre>
<code class="language-markup">
  <form class="send-to-mobile" method="post">
    <input type="text" pattern="[0-9]*" name="phone_number" class="phone_number" />
    <input type="submit" value="Text Me" />
  </form>
  <div class="thanks-message">
    <p>The link will be delivered momentarily</p>
  </div>
</code>
</pre>
```

Comment: you need to encode all of the html metacharacters. `<` -> `&lt;`. `<pre>` doesn't NOT render html. it just tells the browser to honor any linebreak characters within the block as if they were `<br>`. e.g it's "PRE"-formatted text, not unrendered text.

Comment: Please post the controller and view code that generates this page.

Comment: I tried escaping all the characters, I ended up switching to Googles Prettify library which was able to detect and run on the HTML.